# Can I show the series convergence by this relabeling method?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

The series is

$$\sum_2^{\infty}\frac {1}{(\log(n))^{\log(n)}}$$

Can I simply relabel the $\log(n)$ with the variable $y$ and use the ratio test on $\frac{1}{y^y}$?  I'd get 0 in the ratio test limit and I conclude that the series converges.

Is this method valid?

Or should I really stick with the integral test instead?  I tried the integral test too, but the integral is hard to evaluate.

Also, the Cauchy Condensation Test is usually helpful for series of logarithms but it doesn't seem useful in this example.

Any hints or solutions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: LaTeX hint: if you prefix 'log' or 'ln' with a backslash it will get appropriate upright font: `\log` renders as $\log$.

Comment: The condensation test works. Using the change of base for logarithms and powers ($a^{\log b} = b^{?}$) works too and is perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, using the Cauchy condensation test, I am stuck with this summand:  $\large \frac {2^n}{n^{nlog(2)}(log(2))^{nlog(2)}}$.  Where can I go from here?  Also, there is a very cool answer offered below by Marco Cantarini, but I'm afraid it may not be valid, since following that move would mean something like $ e^{(log(log(2))}$ evaluates to $\large 2^{log}$, which I believe doesn't make sense.  I'll also review how to change bases of logarithms now too.  Please feel free to comment further.  Thanks so much,

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, I solved it with the root test, applied to the condensed summand that I wasn't able to simplify.  Wish I had noticed it myself, though - I got it with a hint from another MSE contributor.  I completely overlooked the root test.  Thanks so much for your time :-)

Comment: Marco's answer is the change of base, $a^{\log b} = b^{\log a}$, with $a = \log n,\, b = n$. It's perfectly valid. For the condensation test, you need to see that for large enough $n$, you have $(n\log 2)^{\log 2} > 3$ (or any constant $> 2$), then you have a majorisation by a convergent geometric series (which of course amounts to the root test).

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much @DanielFischer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}}=\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\log\left(\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}\right)\right)}=\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}}
 $$ and so, for example, for a sufficient large $N
 $ we have $\forall n\geq N
 $ that $n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}>n^{2}
 $ hence $$\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}}\leq\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty.
 $$

Comment: Hi @MarcoCantarini, I'm concerned that your move is not valid:  you inverted the log which plays the role of the argument of the first log.  But if we look at for example $e^{(log(log2))}$ and do the same thing you did, I arrive at $\large 2^{log}$ ... which is nonsensical.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi! What I did is using the identity $y=\exp(\log(y))$ with $y=(\log(n))^{\log(n)}$ and then the property $\log(a^{b})=b\log(a).$If it's not clear, I can add some passages if you want ;)

Comment: Oh, gosh - this is awesome, @MarcoCantarini.  You're absolutely right.  And the exact value of N would just be  $\large N = e^e$ - requiring log(log(n)) to be greater than 1, for p-series convergence.  Thanks so much for following up on this answer :-)

Comment: @LebronJames You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *asymptotic analysis*:

Compare the series with the *Bertrand's series*: $\;\displaystyle\sum\frac1{n\log^2n}$, which converges.
$$\log\biggl(\frac{n\log^2n}{\log n^{\log n}}\biggr)=\log n+2\log\log n-\log n\log\log n$$
Now $\;\log n\;$ and $\;\log\log n\;$ are $\;o(\log n\log\log n)$, hence
$$\log\biggl(\frac{n\log^2n}{\log n^{\log n}}\biggr)\sim_\infty-\log n\log\log n\to -\infty. $$
This proves $\;\dfrac{n\log^2n}{\log n^{\log n}}$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, which means $\;\dfrac1{\log n^{\log n}}=o\biggl(\dfrac1{n\log^2n}\biggr)$, hence the series converges.

Comment: Thanks as usual, @Bernard :-)